# How does postgres stores row in page, when row size exceeds available free size in page ?

Tags: postgresql

I am exploring storage mechanism of postgres. I know that postgres is using page like structure(each of size 8K) to store rows. One page can contain more than one row. I also know that TOASTing is done by postgres, when the row can not be contained in given page.

But I am not certain about following scerio :-

- There's only 1K space left in current page, and the size of newly created row exceeds one 1K. In that case, what will happen ? Will new page be allocated for that row and old page will have unused space ? OR the old page's remaining space will be occupied, when another row with size less than or equal to 1K is created ?

I am referring [TOAST](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST). Following para is bit unclear :-

> When a row that is to be stored is "too wide" (the threshold for that is 2KB by default), the TOAST mechanism first attempts to compress any wide field values. If that isn't enough to get the row under 2KB, it breaks up the wide field values into chunks that get stored in the associated TOAST table. Each original field value is replaced by a small pointer that shows where to find this "out of line" data in the TOAST table. TOAST will attempt to squeeze the user-table row down to 2KB in this way, but as long as it can get below 8KB, that's good enough and the row can be stored successfully.

Why it's talking about two sizes 8K and 2K ? Why postgres checks for threshold 2K ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I should clarify that “enough room in the table page” has nothing to do with the question if an attribute is TOASTed or not.

The paragraph you quote describes how **TOAST tries to reduce the size of a table row that exceeds 2KB** by first compressing the values and then storing them “out of line” in a TOAST table.

The idea is to reduce the size such that a row does not use up more than a quarter of the space in a table block. But if that fails, and the row ends up bigger than 2KB after TOASTing, that is no problem either, as long if the resulting row fits into one 8KB block.

**A table row is always stored in a single table block.** If there is not enough space left in any existing block, a new table block is allocated and the existing blocks are left with some empty space. This empty space can still be used for other, smaller new rows.

The limits of 8KB for a table block and 2KB for the threshold for TOASTing are somewhat arbitrary and based on experience. You can change them if you are ready to recompile PostgreSQL (from PostgreSQL v11 on, you can specify the block size when you create the database cluster with `initdb`), but I have not heard any reports that this is a good idea.

Comment: Will using the empty space in old page for new rows, affect the index ? I mean, if in the table, data is sorted by primary index(you can say cluster index, though postgres doesn't support it purely like sql server, as per my knowledge), won't it violate the situation, where in the table rows are sorted and stored according to primary index column ?

Comment: There is no primary index in PostgreSQL. The table is an unordered heap; order is maintained through indexes. Whenever you `UPDATE` a row, it changes position anyway. That said, there is the `CLUSTER` command to order a table in a certain way; this speeds up certain queries.

Comment: If postgres uses, unordered heap, then I guess postgres table index must be very much fragmented. And also index scan(and sequential scan too) must be comparatively slow. Correct me, If I am wrong.

Comment: That depends on how you define "fragmented". There is not much unnecessary free space in the tables. Sequential scans are very fast, index scans not so much because they have to access the table in random order. That's why there are "index only scans" and "bitmap index scans" in PostgreSQL.

Comment: What is difference between "index scan" and "index only scan" ? You said that sequential scan is faster than index scan. Does this hold true for all the cases ? Does Postgres query planner gives more priority to sequential scan than index scan ?

Comment: The difference between an index scan and an index only scan is that the latter does not have to visit the table, because all the information is in the index, and the tuple is visible. PostgreSQL prefers a sequential scan if and only if it is faster than an index scan. I suggest that you read the documentation if you want to know how PostgreSQL works.

Comment: Can you share documentation related to index and index only scan ? Still I am not clear on index only scan ? Normally indices are consulted to get the actual location of row(in faster way). But, if index only scan doesn't requires the table access, then in what scenarios, it's used ?

Comment: Read [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) about index only scans. An index only scan is used if a) all the required information is stored in the index and b) all table rows are visible for everybody.